# change the format of the smallint datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with NUMBER as my PRIMARY KEY, the datatype is SMALLINT. How do I format the values of that field so that instead of 1 it will dislay as 0001 and so on? Thanks! BTW I am using the mySQL workbench 5.2.40

Answer (score 2):

Change it to `SMALLINT(4) ZEROFILL`. The zerofill will left-pad the number with zeroes to the specified length.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting should be done on demand, in my opinion, not in the schema.

```
SELECT LPAD(id, 4, '0') FROM ...
```